# PHPUnit Coverage is ... moving

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, pcov

I have a symfony application codebase. I run phpunit on it, and some classes are sometimes part of the code coverage, and sometimes, they are not.

Because of that, the code coverage percentage is randomly moving.

It's really confusing and it only happens in this specific project.

I use pcov for the code coverage.

I checked phpunit.xml and some files that should not be ignored, are ignored most of the time.

Is there a way with phpunit to have a list of the files taken into account for the code coverage ?

Edit :

I launch the tests with : `phpunit --testdox --testsuite app --coverage-html coverage`

Comment: _"Is there a way with phpunit to have a list of the files taken into account for the code coverage ?"_ Yes, absolutely. Check the documentation, both as flags for the test-runner as well as the configuration file. And keep in mind, that coverage can only be captured for the code run during tests, and different test-suites or directories or files may be run as tests only. Last but not least perhaps the order of tests matters and running tests in a random order may produce this result on your end. Clarify your test-runner invocation in your question please by editing it in. Also exemplary output

Comment: thank you @hakre . I did check the documentation but not well enough apparently. Can you point me in the right direction ?
I didn't know about the order of the tests mattered. Are you sure about that ?

Comment: Example: If running with stop on error/warning/failure/notice/skipped/…, given a set of n files containing tests, when the order of files is random, then coverage is random, too, if one of those tests in a file stops, as a random amount of code has been covered until stop. Order of tests in the documentation: https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.0/configuration.html#the-executionorder-attribute (on the same page you can find the stop on …, c.f. https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.0/configuration.html#the-stopondefect-attribute.) + https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.0/configuration.html#the-coverage-element etc.